# Image Steganography tool which works on linux and mobile platforms

Tags: cryptography, image-conversion

This is the first time I am trying steganography tools. I am looking for an image steganography tool which works on Linux and mobile platforms. The secret message can be embedded in the image on Linux, and should be retrievable on an ios and android app. Any app which is compatible with steghide's output will also work. Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: The simplest means of image steganography is to hide your message in the metadata of an image file, such as an `iTXt` chunk of a PNG. Any image metadata editor should suffice.